# Angular '$resource' definition supplies only one record instead of all

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using `bourne` as a `json` provider. I am trying to fetch all the data from a json file, but i am getting only single data...

what is wrong here:

$resource destination :

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
    .factory('Contact', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/contact/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
            'update':{method:'PUT'}
        });
})
```

My controller :

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
    .controller('ListController',  function($scope, Contact){
        $scope.contacts = Contact.query(); //returns only one...
        $scope.fields = ['firstName', 'lastName'];


        $scope.sort = function (field) {
            $scope.sort.field = field;
            $scope.sort.order = !$scope.sort.order;
        }

        $scope.sort.field = 'firstName';
        $scope.sort.order = false;
    })
```

Comment: Does anything get logged server side when you `GET /contacts`?

Comment: In browser you mean?

Comment: Nothing logged in server side, when i locate the 'contacts' in browser.

Comment: You are logging the `data` variable right now. Try logging the `err` variable.

Comment: In the client-side code, can you show your Contact $resource definition?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
$scope.contacts = Contact.query();
```

Doesn't work like that (just tried). Should be written like this:

```
//returns all
Contacts.query(function(contacts){
    $scope.contacts = contacts;
});
```

Maybe that's the reason and you have hardcoded a result somewhere...